# +/- 96 V transformer less power supply design

Tags: power-supply, vacuum-tube, transformerless

I know this is a dangerous practice, but obtaining a transformer to make a vacuum tube power supply in my country is prohibitively expensive. So i have to go for transformer less psu. I am just making a very simple TUBE tester to check if the grid voltage is really controlling the plate current. Now this requires both + and - power supply. I should be able to completely cutoff plate current by making grid negative. I am presenting my design of power supply.  Have anybody designed something similar? Correct me if some flaw in my design.[image]

Comment: I think you swapped the +96V and the -96V. How much current do you expect to get out of this?

Comment: Transformers aren't hard to come by, go find an old product and rip one out of an old unit. It might be more difficult to find 1:1 or the like but probably worth it

Comment: The X-type capacitor is designed to fail *short*. I don't think you would want that behavior, placed as it is. Perhaps a Y2 here?

Comment: Yes, X class should go *between* live and neutral. Shouldn't a Y class go between Live and Ground?

Comment: I have corrected the +/- markings now thanks for pointing out. I capacitor fails short the the 100mA fuse should save me from fire. Correct me if i am wrong. Ok I will place one Y cap between line and ground.

Answer (score 1):

Your bridges have the diodes swapped compared to the +/- markings.

The bridges short out the capacitively coupled voltage. Try it with four 2uF capacitors rather than a single 1uF.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. Can you please elaborate how bridges short out the capacitively coupled voltage. I need to go deep onto this. Which 1 uF capacitor you are referring to? This circuit do not have any 1 uF capacitor. Please elaborate

Comment: I have corrected the markings. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I see two 0.47uF caps in parallel so about 1uF, right? Follow the current paths through all the diodes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I followed the current path in the bridges and can see what you meant. It shorts out the line. This design have fundamental problem.  Can anybody suggest a dual ended transformer less PSU with current capacity approx 5 mA max. 5mA is enough for my application. Output voltage can be anything from 100 v to 300 v. Again thanks a lot for your support and guidance.